# разорвались связи между продуктами и файлами woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Было нужно поменять места расположения уже загруженных файлов. До этого все файлы располагались в папках по датам, теперь я все перенес в папку uploads. Далее в базе данных поменял все пути к файлам. uploads/2017/01/file.doc на uploads/file.doc Все получилось в медиа библиотеке файлов все отображалось как и должно быть. Но позже заметил, что все мои файлы пропали из продуктов (woocommerce). У меня скачиваемые продукты с прицепленными файлами. В базе данных я вижу что по ID они остались привязанными, но они почему то больше не связаны. На пример:

```
(18370, 1358, '_downloadable_files', 'a:1:{s:32:\"cf099301da794922b99eb1ef2cb9c0d7\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:0:\"\";s:4:\"file\";s:99:\"https://site.com/wp-content/uploads/file.doc\";}}'),
```

В чем может быть проблема? Как расшифровать этот код? Возможно ли еще как то связать файлы с продуктами не прицепляя все с ноля вручную?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> В чем может быть проблема? Как расшифровать этот код?

Это [сериализованный массив](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php).

```
s:32:"cf099301da794922b99eb1ef2cb9c0d7"
```

Здесь 32 — это длина строки, а `cf099301da794922b99eb1ef2cb9c0d7` — сама строка. Если указанная длина не совпадает с реальной — весь массив считается испорченным, и `unserialize()` возвращает `false`. При замене `uploads/2017/01/` на `uploads/` именно это и произошло — длина строк сократилась на 8 символов.

Выполнять подобную замену можно только с помощью инструментов, которые корректно работают с сериализованными данными — например, [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) или [Search Replace DB](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

> Возможно ли еще как то связать файлы с продуктами не прицепляя все с
>   ноля вручную?

Как вариант — откатить изменения и сделать замену корректно.

Answer (score 1):

> В чем может быть проблема?

В том, что полез в базу руками. Никогда так больше не делай. Если есть возможность - откати бекап базу. 
Я не могу представить чем могло помешать логичное расположение файлов, но для изменения таких вещей есть плагины. Они используют АПИ ВП.

> Как расшифровать этот код?

Это не "код", а запись в базе (и что-то ме подсказывает, что кривая - экранирование кавычек тут быть не должно). Изменив тут путь к файлам ты поломал сериализованные данные.

> Возможно ли еще как то связать файлы с продуктами не прицепляя все с
>   ноля вручную?

Скорее нет, чем да. Разве что провести обратную операцию и не придумывать себе проблем на ровном месте.
Ну или разобраться с сериализованными данным и ВРУЧНУЮ изменить их значение в базе :)